# MySQL cluster fast inserts but slow selects

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-cluster, ndbcluster, query-performance

I have a MySQL cluster with 3 Data Nodes and one SQL node. Currently I have 1 million 1kb records. The inserts are very fast, takes only a few ms. But the selects are very slow >20s.

All machines are m1.large EC2 instances (8GB RAM).

Here is the config.ini:

```
[NDB_MGMD]
NodeId=49
HostName=host1
DataDir=/var/lib/mysql-mgmd-data
Portnumber=1186

[NDBD DEFAULT]
NoOfReplicas=1
DataMemory=1536M
IndexMemory=2560M
StringMemory=25
MaxNoOfTables=4096
MaxNoOfOrderedIndexes=2048
MaxNoOfUniqueHashIndexes=512
MaxNoOfAttributes=24576
MaxNoOfTriggers=14336

FragmentLogFileSize=256M
InitFragmentLogFiles=SPARSE
NoOfFragmentLogFiles=16
RedoBuffer=48M
MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations=100000
MaxNoOfConcurrentTransactions=16384
TimeBetweenGlobalCheckpoints=1000
TimeBetweenEpochs=100
TimeBetweenEpochsTimeout=32000

DiskCheckpointSpeedInRestart=100M
DiskCheckpointSpeed=10M
TimeBetweenLocalCheckpoints=20

HeartbeatIntervalDbDb=15000
HeartbeatIntervalDbApi=15000

MemReportFrequency=30
BackupReportFrequency=10
LogLevelStartup=15
LogLevelShutdown=15
LogLevelCheckpoint=8
LogLevelNodeRestart=15

SharedGlobalMemory=384M
DiskPageBufferMemory=1G
BatchSizePerLocalScan=512
[NDBD]
NodeId=1
HostName=host2
DataDir=/mnt/mysql-cluster/1/
[NDBD]
NodeId=2
HostName=host3
DataDir=/mnt/mysql-cluster/2/
[NDBD]
NodeId=3
HostName=host4
DataDir=/mnt/mysql-cluster/3/
[MYSQLD DEFAULT]
[MYSQLD]
NodeId=53
HostName=host1
```

my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
ndbcluster
ndb-nodeid=53
ndb-connectstring=host1,
```

Insert:

```
INSERT INTO mytab(mykey, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i,j)VALUES (1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0);
```

Select:

```
SELECT * FROM mytab WHERE mykey = 12345;
```

Create table statement:

```
 mytab | CREATE TABLE `mytab` (
  `mykey` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `a` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `d` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `e` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `f` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `g` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `h` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `i` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `j` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`mykey`)
) /*!50100 TABLESPACE mytab_space STORAGE DISK */ ENGINE=ndbcluster DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 MAX_ROWS=1000000000
/*!50100 PARTITION BY KEY (mykey) */ |
```

Has someone an idea why it is so slow?
Has someone experience with MySQL-cluster and EC2 m1.large instances?

Comment: Please post INSERT and SELECT examples. If your SELECTs are doing full scans or large range scans - 20s is not fully unexpected. MySQL Cluster is quite slow at those. And I do not think that EC2 is good place for Cluster. Data nodes are quite latency sensitive.

Comment: so you mean 10-20seconds for a select on a database containing 1 million 1kb records is normal?

Comment: MySQL Cluster, EC2 and disk storage. No pun intended but you did everything to slow down things as much as possible. :)
Still 20s for primary key lookup sounds way too slow. Look http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-cluster-ndbd-definition.html#mysql-cluster-ndbd-definition-disk-data-parameters about disk data caching. And maybe you should try usual memory tables? Memory should be enough for your stated ~1GB of data.

Comment: damn, I want to increase the dataset to 35-45 million. So thanks, but you don't see any big mistake in the confi.ini??

Answer (score 1):

It seems that for solving your problem you chose the wrong tool.

MySQL Cluster is good when you do mostly key based lookups from multiple threads from memory based tables. Disk based tables may be useful when you have rarely read data. Or your work dataset is small portion of the table which should fit into memory cache whose size is defined by [DiskPageBufferMemory](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-cluster-ndbd-definition.html#ndbparam-ndbd-diskpagebuffermemory) config variable.

If your queries need many range or full scans - MySQL Cluster is slow even on physical machines. That is because such queries need a lot of data exchanges between data nodes. Try pinging between your data nodes. And for range scan data nodes may need to exchange hundreds and thousands of such messages.

Also MySQL previously stated that for data nodes your should use physical machines and have good interconnect for data node traffic. I doubt that this recommendation is no more valid nowadays.

And I think you should try cleaning up your config. For testing most of those things hardly changes anything and some setting may be slowing down things. Try such simplified `NDBD_DEFAULT` section:

```
[NDBD DEFAULT]
NoOfReplicas=1
DataMemory=1536M
IndexMemory=2560M

LockPagesInMainMemory=2
ODirect=1
```

Comment: I have also tried it without tablespaces, memory only ->same result. Anyway thank you

Comment: What is ping latency between data nodes? And I updated answer about config.

Comment: Ping results: rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.286/0.319/0.373/0.031 ms
I replaced my config with yours, no improvement

Answer (score 0):

[image]i have also faced the same issue while testing my ndb cluster against a standalone innodb engine. when i made a read request to fetch the first 1000 rows of a table, the innodb one was very fast at it taking 230ms, on the other hand ndb cluster took 8 secs. But if i do a key based look up with WHERE ID = "" , in this case ndb cluster is faster even with 500 concurrent request!
My cluster setup was 1 SQL node, 1 Manager Node, 4 Datanodes with no. of fragment repilca was set 4.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your support!
I guess it was my fault. The code I used was wrong. Is used setBytes(..) instead of setString(..).
The latency dropped down from 20s to 4s. 4s is still not comparable with a NoSQL db like mongodb, but I guess there is not that much to improve.

```
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO "+ table+" VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, key);
            for(int i=0; i<byteArray.length; i++){
                preparedStatement.setString(i+2, byteArray[i].toString());
            }
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            preparedStatement.close();
```